# How to get content inside an HTML <ol> From URLwith python

Tags: python, html-lists, discord.py, replit

I am trying to make a discord bot using python for my friend’s Warframe clan that **scrapes content from the [Warframe PC Announcements section](http://forums.warframe.com/forum/2-pc-announcements/?sortby=start_date&sortdirection=desc)**. **I was wanting to use the discord bot to send it as an Embed in the Discord Chat**

Here is some code I have tried

```py
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml


url = "http://forums.warframe.com/forum/2-pc-announcements/?sortby=start_date&sortdirection=desc"
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import lxml
sess = requests.Session()
page = sess.get(url)
page = BeautifulSoup(page.text, features="lxml")
soap = page.select('li.item', features="lxml")
print([s.find('li').text for s in soap])
```

Comment: There's no code and no actual question here. Have a read of https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @TomDalton I added some code, and a question

Answer (score 0):

Although your title asks one thing, your question asks another.

To get content from an ordered list:

```
for item in ordered_list:

    # This is where you would do things to your item
    new_thing = foo(item)

    return new_thing
```

To get content from an ordered list and pass the index:

```
for idx, item in enumerate(ordered_list):

    # This is where you would do things to your item
    new_thing = foo(item)

    return idx, new_thing
```

---

As for the body of your question. You state that `everything I've tried has failed`, what exactly have you tried though?

Well I can't tell you how to do this, I can point you towards topics that will help:

- [Web Scraping (Beautiful Soup)](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/)
- [Discord Bots (Making One In Python)](https://realpython.com/how-to-make-a-discord-bot-python/)

**If you give more information the community can provide better answers.**

Comment: I fixed my question.